# Upgrade Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL from 9.6 to 10

Tags: postgresql, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I am trying to upgrade **Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL** from verion `9.6` to `10.14` via CloudFormation template command `aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name base --template-body file://cloudformation/base.yml` but every time update is getting rollback with one of the below messages:

1. **Unmodifiable DB Parameter: wal_consistency_checking**
2. **Unmodifiable DB Parameter: ssl_dh_params_file**

Here's the part of `base.yml` looks like:

```
DatabaseCustomParameterGroupIdentifier:
  Description: ID of the database parameter group
  Value: !Ref DatabaseCustomParameterGroup
  Export:
    Name: DatabaseCustomParameterGroupIdentifier

DatabaseCustomParameterGroup:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
  Properties:
    Description: Database Custom Parameter Group
    Family: aurora-postgresql10
    Parameters:
      pg_stat_statements.track: ALL
      shared_preload_libraries: pg_stat_statements
      track_activity_query_size: 2048
      pglogical.use_spi: true
      pglogical.synchronous_commit: true
      temp_file_limit: "-1"
      ssl_dh_params_file: ""
      wal_consistency_checking: 'all'
```

I have taken the reference of these 2 parameters from these links: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-developer.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-connection.html

[EDIT-I]
I can see both these parameters inside RDS > Parameter Groups with Modifiable value as `false`

[image]

Also, when I tried deleting the Parameter group, I got this message:

```
Failed to delete default.aurora-postgresql10: Default DBParameterGroup cannot be deleted: default.aurora-postgresql10 (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDBParameterGroupState).
```

Please advise what am I doing wrong here!

[EDIT-II]

If I try to remove these 2 parameters and run the CF command again, I am getting this:

```
The following parameters are not defined for the specified group: ssl_dh_params_file, wal_consistency_checking (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue)
```

[EDIT-III]

1. As per AWS docs, I cannot delete a default parameter group. Perhaps this is a reason for the above error when I am trying to delete this Parameter group?
2. Here's what I can see from the console if I see the properties of these 2 parameters:

```
    {
      "ParameterName": "wal_consistency_checking",
      "Description": "Sets the WAL resource managers for which WAL consistency checks are done.",
      "Source": "engine-default",
      "ApplyType": "dynamic",
      "DataType": "string",
      "IsModifiable": false,
      "MinimumEngineVersion": "10.4",
      "ApplyMethod": "pending-reboot"
    },
    {
      "ParameterName": "ssl_dh_params_file",
      "Description": "Location of the SSL DH parameters file.",
      "Source": "engine-default",
      "ApplyType": "dynamic",
      "DataType": "string",
      "IsModifiable": false,
      "MinimumEngineVersion": "10.4",
      "ApplyMethod": "pending-reboot"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those who are finding it difficult to upgrade, here's what I did:

- Updated the base template and added `AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup` settings for Postgres 10 version
- After that I executed `aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name base --template-body file://cloudformation/base.yml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM` command to update the base stack
- Then I executed: `aws rds modify-db-cluster` command from console

```
$ aws rds modify-db-cluster \
>     --db-cluster-identifier DB_CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER \
>     --engine-version 10.14 \
>     --db-cluster-parameter-group-name default.aurora-postgresql10 \
>     --db-instance-parameter-group-name base-dbcustomparametergroup-pg10 \
>     --allow-major-version-upgrade \
>     --apply-immediately \
>     --debug
```

- Lastly, I executed CF command for the dedicated Rails environment: `aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name staging --template-body file://cloudformation/template.yml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

You can obtain the value of `db-instance-parameter-group-name` after updating your base stack and copy the name of AWS > RDS > Parameter Group